# Sitefinity - Safely delete orphaned dynamic content records

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-dynamic-content-types

I've been adding records to a dynamic module via the API and in the process during my experimentation I added a bunch of records that weren't associated correctly with any valid parent record.

I've checked and so far I can see that Sitefinity stores data about these records in a number of tables:

1. *mydynamiccontenttype_table*
2. sf_dynamic_content
3. sf_dynmc_cntnt_sf_lnguage_data
4. sf_dynmc_cntent_sf_permissions

I would like to clean up the database by deleting these records but I want to make sure I don't create more problems in the process.

Anyone know if there are more references to these dynamic content type records or a process to safely delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably other tables, so your safest option would be to delete the items using the Sitefinity API.

Just get the masterId of the item and use a code like this:

```
public static void DeleteDataItemOfType(this DynamicModuleManager manager, string type, Guid Id)
    {
        Type resolvedType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(type);

        using (var region = new ElevatedModeRegion(manager))
        {
            manager.DeleteDataItem(resolvedType, Id);

            manager.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```